# Forwarding Path With .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I use cPanel hosting on `https://files.example.com` and I'd like `https://files.example.com/anything-here` to redirect to my main website and forward the path, so you'd end up on `https://www.example.com/anything-here`. Is this possible?

Note that I also have a forced SSL redirect inside my `.htaccess` file.

`https://www.example.com` is a Google Site.

My `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /index.html
ErrorDocument 401 /index.html
ErrorDocument 403 /index.html
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
ErrorDocument 500 /index.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
```

Comment: Do `files.example.com` and `www.example.com` point to the same place? Same filesystem but different subdirectory? Or completely different servers? Please post the contents of your existing `.htaccess` file(s).

Comment: No. ```https://www.rydercragie.com``` is a Google Site.

Currently my .htaccess file just points to my error page, but of course that can be changed to achieve what I want to do. And of course I have the forced SSL redirect.

```ErrorDocument 400 /index.html
ErrorDocument 401 /index.html
ErrorDocument 403 /index.html
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
ErrorDocument 500 /index.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `https://www.example.com` is a Google Site.

If the two sites are on different servers and you simply need to redirect everything from one host to the other and maintain the same URL-path then you don't appear to need anything in your `.htaccess` file at `files.example.com` except for the following mod_alias `Redirect` directive:

```
# Redirect everything to https://www.example.com/ and maintain URL-path
Redirect 302 / https://www.example.com/
```

The `Redirect` directive is prefix matching and everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target URL. So, a request for `/foo` is redirected to `https://www.example.com/foo`.

If, however, you have other hostnames pointing to your cPanel account then you'll need to use a mod_rewrite rule and check the requested hostname.

For example, at the end of your existing `.htaccess` file:

```
# Redirect every request for "files.example.com"
#   to https://www.example.com/ and maintain URL-path
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^files\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

---

**UPDATE#1:**

> But I just realised that it's also forwarding the path for files that do exist on my hosting. I onlt want it to forward invalid paths through to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

In that case, you'll need to do it like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^files\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

The 2nd and 3rd *conditions* check that the request does not map to an existing file (or directory) before issuing the redirect.

Remove the first condition that checks the `HTTP_HOST` if it's not required.

---

**UPDATE#2:**

> Is there a way to have it exclude "/URL" from this? If "URL" is specified in the path (example.com/URL/whatever) then I do not want this .htaccess rule to take place. I just want it to use my ErrorDocuments for this path.

If it's just the one *pattern* you want to exclude, ie. all URLs that *start* `/URL` then you can modify just the `RewritRule` directive. For example:

```
:
RewriteRule !^URL https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Any URLs that do not start `/URL` will be excluded. Note that this also includes `/URLwhatever`, not just `/URL/whatever`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works!!! Can I remove the ErrorDocuments now? Or should I leave them there?

Comment: If you only have the one host and are using the first method (`Redirect` directive) then you can remove _everything_ else and just leave the `Redirect` directive.

Comment: Okay. But I just realised that it's also forwarding the path for files that do exist on my hosting. I only want it to forward invalid paths through to `www.example.com`.

Comment: @RyderCragie Ah OK, so `/anything-here` should really be `/anything-that-does-not-exist-here`! I've updated my answer.

Comment: I am way too excited that this is working now. Thank you so much!!! I spent hours Googling it and got nowhere. You are a life-saver!!!

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help and have a great day. 

Comment: Is there a way to have it exclude "/URL" from this? If "URL" is specified in the path (example.com/URL/whatever) then I do not want this .htaccess rule to take place. I just want it to use my ErrorDocuments for this path.

Comment: @RyderCragie I've updated my answer (UPDATE#2) to allow URLs that start `/URL` to be excluded.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I already had. You are awesome! Thank you!